# How is AngleSharp's Document.DocumentUri different from Document.Url?

Tags: c#, dom, anglesharp

- `Document.Url`: "Gets a string containing the URL of the current document."
- `Document.DocumentUri`: "Gets a string containing the URL of the current document."

What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties correspond to DOM properties of the same names.

Per MDN:

> HTML documents have a document.URL property which returns the same value [as document.documentURI]. Unlike URL, documentURI is available on all types of documents. ([source](http://web.archive.org/web/20170917105053/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentURI))

So theoretically, only `Document.DocumentUri` is guaranteed to always return a value.

In my testing, though, both properties are set for non-HTML documents in Chrome and Edge (text files, PNGs, INIs).